# Karate API - stored response in def then reuse same in path next url

Tags: karate

unable to pass stored response ID in next path

stored * def A = response.ActiveScriptJobID 
Tried like   And path '#A'

```
Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/createjob/86/'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response contains {ActiveScriptJobID: "#present"}
* def resp = response
* def A = response.ActiveScriptJobID
* print A
#here 'A' variable stores new created active script job ID

Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/startjob/'
And path '#A'
When method get
Then status 200
```

IT should reuse created job ID in next Testcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try directly using the variable without embedded expression

```
* def A = response.ActiveScriptJobID
Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/startjob/'
And path A
When method get
Then status 200
```